# Deep learning activation function between hidden layers?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

I am kinda confused what is the use of the activation between hidden layers, I know the softmax function between hidden layers and output is squeeze the probabilities to [0,1], but what is the use of sigmoid function between hidden layers?
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The purpose is to add non-linear behavior to the network, without it the number of functions that can be represented is lower, and if you have no non-linear activation functions, the network is completely linear, which is not very useful for most problems.

Each layer that adds non-linear activations also contributes on the non-linear behavior of the network output. That is one reason why adding more layers improves accuracy, as the network can better represent different functions.

Comment: I would like to add the [Universal Approximation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem) which states that a neural net with at least one (nonlinear) hidden layer (of infinite size) can approximate any function.

Comment: "the network is completely linear, which is not very useful for most problems" -- actually, you can collapse multi-layer linear nets into a single layer, so there is no benefit of adding linear layers in the first place.

Comment: @cheersmate Really? I recall from class that xor is a simple example of a function that cannot be expressed using a single layer. How would you collapse a multi-layer net for xor into a single layer?

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn cheersmate is talking about multiple linear layers, for xor you need multiple non-linear layers. Not the same.

Answer (score 0):

1. The output of sigmoid is not 0 centered. It cannot handle negative values efficiently.
2. Tanh can cause the problem of busting gradients.

According to latest research ,one should use ReLU function in the hidden layers of deep neural networks ( or leakyReLU if the vanishing gradient is faced ). 
With this the output layer must have a softmax for classification or a linear activation for regression.

I learned it from [this](https://youtu.be/-7scQpJT7uo) great video.